# Why Apache ignore my VirtualHost declaration?

Tags: apache, https, xampp, virtualhost

Apache (from XAMPP) dont work like expected.
When I type https://myVirtualHost, I would join "C:/xampp/htdocs/myApplication/public/"
But apache show me "C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php"

Here my VirtualHost declaration :

```
<VirtualHost *:433>
    ServerName myVirtualHost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myApplication/public"
    ErrorLog "logs/myApplication-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myApplication-access.log" common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

And my "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" declaration :

```
127.0.0.1 myVirtualHost
```

Any idea ? Thanks

EDIT : I precise :
`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is active in "httpd.conf" and work well for all "*80 virtual hosts. Only *443 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Please try to check the file: httpd.conf
>
> Uncomment:
>
> ```
> Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
> ```
>
> If you uncommented it and set your setting on the httpd-vhosts.conf,
>   please restart.

Here's I know on my practice:

https://github.com/oliguo/Server-Deployment/blob/master/XAMPP.md#ssl-setup-with-xamppauthorized-with-godaddy

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/youdomain_A"
    ServerName youdomain_A
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/youdomain_A/youdomain_A.crt" ->from godady
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/youdomain_A.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/youdomain_A/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt" ->from godaddy
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/youdomain_A/">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/youdomain_A/domain_ssl_error_log"
    ErrorDocument 404 https://youdomain_A 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this line is always active :)

Comment: @bArraxas is there 'NameVirtualHost *:443' and check the httpd.conf is there a thing like ErrorDocument 404